# Postgres SQL: Sum of ids greater than a day, computed day by day over a series

Tags: sql, postgresql

Looking to compute a moving sum day by day over a date range. i.e. Looking to sum all values greater than or equal to the date but do it row by row. I know that a window function is needed, but need some help with the actual function.

** I need to compute the sum greater than each date in a row. Notice on 2017-08-02 I do not count the value from the day before

Example data:

```
2017-08-1, 1
2017-08-2, 5
2017-08-3, 4
2017-08-4, 3
2017-08-5, 2
```

Desired Result:

```
2017-08-1, 15
2017-08-2, 14
2017-08-3, 9
2017-08-4, 5
2017-08-5, 2
```

Here is what I have to produce this data.

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('day', created_at),
   COUNT(*)
FROM table
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use cumulative sums:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('day', created_at),
       COUNT(*),
       SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER BY DATE_TRUNC('day', created_at) DESC) as sum_greater_than
FROM table
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1 DESC;
```

Comment: I added a comment on my original post. I need to do this sum, but I need to not count the values from days less than the day at hand in each row. Thank you

Comment: Nvm, this is all I need. Thanks!